# Enter key on hidden submit button not working in chrome but works well in mozila and opera

Tags: html, google-chrome

I have a login page which requires username and password to move to home page.

So I have two fields one for username and another for password. After entering username and password you have to press the enter key(from the keyboard) because I have hidden the submit button.

I have tested in mozilla firefox and opera browser and it works perfectly but in google chrome its not working. Please tell me how to do.

```
   <%@ page import="java.sql.*" %>
<%@ page import="DB.*" %>
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8"
    pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
<title>Spanwave</title>
<meta name="keywords" content="" />
<meta name="description" content="" />
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>DiaEmr</title>

<link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" />




<script type="text/javascript">
function ccheck()
{
uid=document.getElementByName('uid').value;
    cpass=document.getElementByName('cpass').value;

if(uid=="" || uid==null)
{
alert("Plz. Enter Your User ID");
document.f1.uid.focus();
return false;
}
if(cpass=="" || cpass==null)
{
alert("Plz. Enter Your Password");
document.f1.cpass.focus();
return false;
}
return true;
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
<%
if(session.getAttribute("login")==null)
{
%>
<div id="menu-wrapper">     <<center><h2>Diabetes Surgery-Data Registry</h2>    </center>
    <div id="menu">

        <ul>

        </ul>
    </div>
    <!-- end #menu --> 
</div>
<div id="banner"><a href="#"><img src="images/img01.jpg" width="1000" height="500" alt="rotating image" id="rotator"></a></div>
<div id="header-wrapper">
    <div id="header">
        <div id="logo">
            <h1><a href="#">Dia<span>EMR</span></a></h1>
            <p>Website design by <a href="http://www.spanwave.com">Spanwave</a></p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div id="wrapper"> 
    <!-- end #header -->
    <div id="page">
        <div id="page-bgtop">
            <div id="page-bgbtm">
                <div id="sidebar">
                    <ul>
                        <li>
                            <h2>Portal    Login</h2>
                            <div >
                                <form id="f1" name="f1" method="post" action="authentication.jsp" onsubmit="return ccheck()">

                                        User Name<input type="text" name="uid" id="search-username" value="" />
                                        Password<input type="password" name="cpass" id="search-password" value="" />
                                        <input type="submit" id="search-submit" value="" /><br><br>New User<a href="UserRegistration.jsp">Register </a>

                                </form>
                            </div>




                    </ul>
                </div>
                <!-- end #sidebar -->
                <div id="content">
                    <div class="post">
                        <h2 class="title">Welcome to DiaEmr </h2>

                        <div style="clear: both;">&nbsp;</div>
                        <div class="entry">
                            <p>welcome to all the <strong>"Workshop on Ileal Interposition".</strong>,
                                                <b>Brazil</b> to inaugurate & launch this very important Data Registry<br>
                                                Key features of the solution-<br>
   -Electronics Medical Records<br>
   -Data Analysis<br>
   -Easy Appointment Scheduling<br>
   -Patient Reminder<br>
   -Anytime,Anywhere Access<br>
   -Highly Secured Data<br>
   -Rich User Interface
                        </div>
                    </div>

                        </div>
                    </div>

                    </div>
                    <div style="clear: both;">&nbsp;</div>
                </div>
                <!-- end #content -->


                <div style="clear: both;">&nbsp;</div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <!-- end #page --> 
</div>
<div id="footer">
    <p>&copy; 2013 Spanwave.com  | Design by <a href="http://www.spanwave.com">Spanwave</a>.</p>
</div>
<!-- end #footer -->
<script type="text/javascript">
    (function() {
        var rotator = document.getElementById('rotator');  
        var imageDir = 'images/';                          
        var delayInSeconds = 5;                           
        // list image names
        var images = ['img02.jpg', 'img03.jpg', 'img04.jpg', 'img01.jpg'];

        // don't change below this line
        var num = 0;
        var changeImage = function() {
            var len = images.length;
            rotator.src = imageDir + images[num++];
            if (num == len) {
                num = 0;
            }
        };
        setInterval(changeImage, delayInSeconds * 1000);
    })();
    </script>
<%}else{response.sendRedirect("frameSet.jsp");}%>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Not working???? This can mean many things?

Comment: @Liam not working means if you press enter then nothing happens

Answer (score 0):

The browser is probably not interpreting the Enter keystroke as a "submit". I had a similar problem and used an eventhandler which listens for a desired keystroke and does the submit via JavaScript. Something like this:

```
function doAfterEvent(evt) {
  evt = (evt) ? evt : ((event) ? event : null);
  if (evt.keyCode == 13) {
    document.logein.submit();
  }
  return;
}
```

Not the best code, but it might set you off in the right direction.

Comment: thanks for answer. Please tell me do i need to write the codes in the page or some editing is required

Answer (score 0):

Remove the srcipt that you wrote twice

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function() {             //HERE
    var rotator = document.getElementById('rotator');  
    var imageDir = 'images/';                          
    var delayInSeconds = 5;                           
    // list image names
    var images = ['img02.jpg', 'img03.jpg', 'img04.jpg', 'img01.jpg'];

    // don't change below this line
    var num = 0;
    var changeImage = function() {
        var len = images.length;
        rotator.src = imageDir + images[num++];
        if (num == len) {
            num = 0;
        }
    };
    setInterval(changeImage, delayInSeconds * 1000);
});          //HERE
</script>
```

and give different ids for

```
User Name<input type="text" name="uid" id="search-username" value="" />
Password<input type="password" name="cpass" id="search-password" value="" />
```

and on function ccheck() try to edit like this

```
function ccheck()
{
    uid=document.getElementByName('uid').value;
    cpass=document.getElementByName('cpass').value;
```

Comment: see i have done as you have said and i have edited the post. Please have a look. It i still not working

Comment: which function you are referring to

Comment: the script which runs onload....$(function() {             //HERE
    var rotator = document.getElementById('rotator'); ........

Comment: Now the image is not rotating as well as not workking in chome