# jquery div show/hide not functioning properly on check or uncheck

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

In my web page there is a field previous suregery and which has certain elements. so if you check the previous surgery then only the previous surgery elements show else wont. 
following is a part of my code but it is not functioning properly. can any one Please tell me

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>

 <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.2/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" />

 <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>



  <link href="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8/themes/base/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
  <script>
$(function(){
   $('.toggler').click(function(){
       if (this.checked) {
           $('div#name').slideDown();
       } else {
           $('div#name').slideUp();
       }
   });
})
  </script>
</head>
<body>
<table>
<tr>

                    <td  height="30">
                        <b>Previous Surgery</b>
                    </td>

                    <td>
<input type="checkbox" name="myCB" value="A" class="toggler" checked="checked" />
                    </td>
                </tr>
<div id="name">

<tr><td>Type of Surgery</td><td><input type="text"></td></tr>
<tr><td>Main Reason for surgery</td><td><input type="text"></td></tr>

<tr><td>Year</td><td><input type="text"></td></tr>
<tr><td>Reffered By</td><td><input type="text"></td></tr>
</div>

</table>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You can't have `<div id="name">` between your `tr`s.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply try like this

```
$(function(){
$('.toggler').click(function(){
   $('div#name').toggle();       
 });
})
```

Try this [**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/V7LxV/10/)

and try to put your div outside of the table,as I have mentioned in the fiddle

Comment: if you do not mind i have another question but its not related to this question. I have posted one question but till now i did not get any answer. My page is not working in google chrome and IE. can you please check it

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16691180/jsp-page-not-working-in-chrome-but-works-well-in-mozila-and-opera

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/30611/discussion-between-gautam3164-and-javal)

Comment: @javaL see that ,i have put ans

Answer (score 2):

Reason is your HTML is invalid.
Div cannot be direct child to `table`.

Fix your HTML:-

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td height="30"> <b>Previous Surgery</b>

        </td>
        <td>
            <input type="checkbox" name="myCB" value="A" class="toggler" checked="checked" />
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
<div id="name">
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td>Type of Surgery</td>
            <td>
                <input type="text">
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Main Reason for surgery</td>
            <td>
                <input type="text">
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Year</td>
            <td>
                <input type="text">
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Reffered By</td>
            <td>
                <input type="text">
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</div>
```

### JS

```
$(function () {
    $('.toggler').click(function () {
        $('#name').slideToggle();
    });
})
```

### [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/HJbnQ/)

If your element has id then use it alone as it is supposed to be unique and less cost effective in performance.

*From [Doc](http://api.jquery.com/id-selector/)*

> For id selectors, jQuery uses the JavaScript function document.getElementById(), which is extremely efficient. When another selector is attached to the id selector, such as h2#pageTitle, jQuery performs an additional check before identifying the element as a match.

So `#name` is better than `div#name`.

Thanks to @Ian

Comment: You can workl around on alignment. here is a better one http://jsfiddle.net/Eg8PF/

Comment: `input` elements don't need to be closed in HTML5, so there's no question of validity there. Also, you shouldn't suggest using `div#name` selector, as the `div` part creates more work than necessary for jQuery to find the element

Comment: Thanks @Ian i wasn't aware of self closing thing for HTML5. but how about the browsers that doesnt support them? But regd input tags to one extend it is tru as they cannot enclose anything else.

Answer (score 0):

<kbd>**[Working FIDDLE Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/mojtaba/tmdA8/)**</kbd>

You can't have `<div id="name">` between your `tr`s. Close your table before `div`, and reopen it again:

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td height="30">
            <b>Previous Surgery</b>
        </td>
        <td>
            <input type="checkbox" name="myCB" value="A" class="toggler" checked="checked" />
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>


<div id="name">
    <table>
        <tr><td>Type of Surgery</td><td><input type="text"></td></tr>
        <tr><td>Main Reason for surgery</td><td><input type="text"></td></tr>
        <tr><td>Year</td><td><input type="text"></td></tr>
        <tr><td>Reffered By</td><td><input type="text"></td></tr>
    </table>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your div element placement is wrong.Put that div in proper place Then  SlideUp and SlideDown methods should work.